# Date displays the wrong month (month - 1)

Tags: swift, date, swift3, dateformatter

I try to display a date from my **Node.js** server in **Swift 3**.

The date is receive in a JSON object, which is then parsed.

The JSON object contains:

```
{
    // ...
    "createdAt": "2018-02-06T09:33:45.438Z"
}
```

I created a function in Swift:

```
class func dateFormatter() -> DateFormatter {
    let aDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    aDateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
    aDateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Paris")
    aDateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR_POSIX")

    return aDateFormatter
}
```

Then, I parse my JSON object:

```
if let dateString = json["createdAt"] as? String {
    self.createdAt = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
    // where createdAt is a Date
}
```

All works, except the fact that my `createdAt` date is one month earlier than the expected month.

**Example:** `6 janv. 2018 à 11:27` instead of `6 fév. 2018 à 11:27`

Comment: Both YYYY and DD are the wrong formats ...

Comment: I can reproduce your original problem with the wrong date format "YYYY-MM-DD", but get a correct result for "yyyy-MM-dd". Can you post a (minimal) *self-contained* program demonstrating the problem? (No JSON, just a string, date formatter, conversion, and printing the result.)

Comment: Thanks it's now working, I forgot to change the format in my different classes.

Comment: That's what I thought ... so it *is* a duplicate (and you should revert your edit and retract the reopen vote).